# C++ merged array output error

Tags: c++, arrays, merge

I want to merge two sorted arrays to to third array and display ascending order. I'm getting an error on output that merged array showing invalid value('zero' digits repeatedly displaying on the screen)

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>


void Merge(int name[], int name2[], int name3[], int temp, int temp2, int &temp3);

void main()
{
    int i,j,size,name[100],name2[100],name3[200],temp,temp2,temp3;
    cout<<"\nHow many numbers Ascending order:";
    cin>>size;

    cout<<"\nEnter Elements: \n";
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cin>>name[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<size-i-1;j++)
     {
      if(name[j]>name[j+1])                                        //just replace > by < for descending order.
      {
      temp=name[j];
      name[j]=name[j+1];
      name[j+1]=temp;
      }

     }
    }
    cout<<"\nAscending order is:";
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    cout<<" "<<name[i];
    }



    cout<<"\n\nHow many numbers for Descending Order:";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"\nEnter Descending Elements: \n";


    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    cin>>name2[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<size-i-1;j++)
     {
      if(name2[j]<name2[j+1])                                        //just replace > by < for descending order.
      {
      temp2=name2[j];
      name2[j]=name2[j+1];
      name2[j+1]=temp2;
      }

     }
    }
    cout<<"\nDescending order is:";
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    cout<<" "<<name2[i];
    }

    Merge(name,name2,name3,temp,temp2,temp3);

        cout<<"\n\nThe Merged Array in Ascending Order"<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<temp3;i++)
        {
            cout<<name3[i]<<" ";
        }


    getch();

}


    void Merge(int name[], int name2[], int name3[], int temp, int temp2, int &temp3)
    {
          int i=0, j=temp2-1;
          temp3=0;
          while (i<temp && j>=0)
          {
            if (name[i]<name2[j])
              name3[temp3++]=name[i++];
            else if (name[i]>name2[j])
              name3[temp3++]=name2[j--];
            else
            {
              name3[temp3++]=name[i++];
              j--;
            }
          }
          for (int t=i;t<temp;t++)
            name3[temp3++]=name[t];
          for (t=j;t>=0;t--)
            name3[temp3++]=name2[t];

    }
```

Comment: Did you already try debugging your code?

Comment: You need something along the lines of taking the next from name1 or name2 depending on which one is larger, and copy any leftovers. Not at all what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Merge` function is taking a copy of name3, adding your values, then discarding the copy when it's done. So your arrays are merged, but you never get the merged array back from the function.

You'll probably want to make `Merge` take a pointer to `name3` instead.

```
void Merge(int name[], int name2[], int *name3, int temp, int temp2, int &temp3);
```

This will allow your function to work on the array itself, rather than a copy. See the 2nd example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm) for reference.

Note: You might also have to pass in the size of `name3`, to avoid out of bounds errors.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have tried above method but getting error when create build. I'm a student of computer science and newbie to C++. I will appreciate if you can help me.